# c++ xml chunk data error

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing

I have a xml reader in C++ and I am making a error function or proofer that only sends complete xml trees to the parser.  The data is in a char array like

```
char chunkdata[245];
```

Then convert it to a string like

```
String data(chunkdata);
```

And parse the data.
This program will get chunked data at any time and process. The only thing with chunked data is that it sometimes sends incomplete xml trees... So I might only get half of a content in a char array  like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
 <to> Tove</to>
 <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Remin
```

And get a few mil seconds later the rest

```
 der</heading>
 <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

And after processing it would produce two strings and crash the program.

What could I add in my code to either wait to add if not complete... or get only the complete xml trees and leave the remaining to add to the rest when it comes... I tried things like string FIND with string   substring which would process then Add the remaining later but it didn't work.. Any suggestions ??? Thank you

Comment: Unless you have enough memory to load the entire file into a string, you will need to take care of "the part I've read is not complete, let's continue in the next part" type scenarios. It doesn't matter if you are reading 245, 3000 or 9000 characters at a time, you will have to deal with it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you're doing is a validator that reads the file in block mode, then you should probably keep track of opened and closed tags in some sort of separate structure. If your buffer can change its length (I'm not sure what `String` is, but `std::string` certainly can change its size during runtime), you probably want to have something similar to the following:

```
std::map<std::string, long> tags;
```

And when you encounter a tag opening, do:

```
if(tags.find(tagName))
   tags[tagName]++;
else
   tags[tagName]=1;
```

And when you encounter a tag closing, do:

```
if(tags.find(tagName))
   tags[tagName]--;
else
   tags[tagName]=-1;
```

The tags are closed properly only if all the elements of the map are equal `0`. Lets assume `testForCorrectness()` does just that. Then your code would look like this:

```
char chunkdata[245];
readSomeData();
String data(chunkdata);
while(!testforCorrectness()){
   readSomeData();
   data += (String)chunkdata;
}
return chunkdata;
```

If you also want to test if the tags were closed in the correct order - try using a `vector` instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> openedTags;
```

On tag begin:

```
openedTags.push_back(tagName);
```

On tag close:

```
if(openedTags.back() == tagName)
   openedTags.pop_back();
else
   // XML is ill-formed
```

Finish if `empty(openedTags)`.